# Inputting text within field box in IE mode on selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to automate a website that is only compatible with Internet Explorer. I managed to get Edge to launch with IE mode enabled, but I'm unable to find the text boxes Selenium.
I have tried using a hard way to ensure that all the html elements have loaded before searching  using:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element cannot be interacted with via the keyboard because it is not displayed

```
ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\IEDriverServer.exe', options=ieOptions)

UserName = driver.find_element(By.ID, "UserName")
UserName.send_keys(ID)
```

HTML

```
<INPUT tabIndex=1 id=UserName class=APP_SelectText style="BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; WIDTH: 210px; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent" maxLength=40 type=password value="">
```

The issue is the same if I use IE instead of Edge.

Picture after run:
[image]

Comment: Any other element with the id Username?

Comment: So, your `UserName` element is not displayed. What does it look like on the screen when you follow this workflow manually? Perhaps there is another element covering it up?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan ok so it looks like there's another element with the same ID.


<TD id=UserName title="User Name" class=standardText rowSpan=2 noWrap></TD>

Comment: @C.Peck image added

Comment: Does your site has "iframe"? Isn't it happening because of that? Providing [mcve] would be great

Comment: Just access the right element or whatever index 2. A simple xpath:  (//input[@id='Username'])[1]

Comment: @Xitiz looks like it was an iframe issue. Had to switch over for it to work. Thanks

Comment: @FallenEgg Would you answer it or should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As [@Xitiz asked in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087298/inputting-text-within-field-box-in-ie-mode-on-selenium/73101394#comment129084792_73087298):

> Does your site has "iframe"? Isn't it happening because of that? Providing minimal reproducible example would be great

It looks like it was an `iframe` issue. I had to switch over for it to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).